# php wso2 ws-security sign only messages without encryption

Tags: php, soap, wso2, ws-security, wso2-identity-server

I need to send a structure via soap which is time marked and cert signed but the body is not encrypted (ws-security mechanism).
How to achieve such result - how to create a message signed with cert but not ecnrypted.
Also I have to add that currently I have cert.p12 from my provider which as far as I know have two keys public and private inside.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following sample folder at https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/trunk/wsf/php/samples/security/signing for an example on how to implement signing with WSF/PHP.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure, but a SOAP request itself can not be encrypted. You only can encrypt ans sign the connection to the server.

Comment: They can be encrypted/signed/timemarked using ws-security mechanisms. That's for sure. However I still don't know how to sign only and time mark my request to ws-security enabled service.

Comment: user630198 has all the reason you can specify rules for encrypting/signing the body using WSP (Web services policy) however not sure about how to do it with WSF/PHP